# Having multiple copies/backups on the same Hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive

Recently I have read somewhere that: -

> If you do not have `3` backups of your important data, you do not have your data.

Now, I have a single `2 TB` HDD. My important files are only of `100 GB` in size.

**My question: -**

> So, can I just create `3` equal partitions in my HDD and backup the
> same file in all the `3` partitions and call it that I have `3`
> backups of my data?

Now of-course I know that backing up my data on `3` separate HDD is a safer solution, but if a person does not have access to different HDD's does the above solution work? or is it just a false sense of security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are defeating the purpose, and a very false sense of security. If you have only 100 gigs if data, cloud backup is cheap.

You have numerous issues with 3 copies on 1 disk - these include -

A big risk is disk failure.  While having 3 copies might provide a bit more robustness here, a disk failure can be catastrophic and kill all your data. This is why most servers use RAID - to reduce the risk - and also why RAID5 is not used (because risk of 2nd failure during rebuild on large disks)

Theft. Your 1 disk could be stolen.  Its not unheard of.

Then you have stuff you might be able to mitigate, but maybe not - if all copies of disk are accessible, cryptolocker type malware can take out all copies at once, as can corruption and firmware issues. The cost of data recovery - if its possible is far far more then good backups.

I'd suggest a practical backup regimine ensures an off-site copy, ideally an off-line copy, and a second nkn- attached copy you can rotate.

While not a panacea, at the level of someone asking this question, cloud backups are a good idea because -

They are cheap.
They are often instant.
They are automatic.
They are versioned.
They are off-site.
They are managed by people with appropriate skills.

(Note that as a rule, I don't like the cloud for anything. That said, for my not technical clients backups are the exception).

If you really don't have the money to spend on backup solutions, can swap backups with a friend or 3?  If its confidential stuff, you could look at something like veracrypt or password protected zip files.

Comment: So basically if a HDD is to fail, it will fail as a whole? Has there been any case where only partition has failed and the rest of HDD survives? or such cases of partition failure are very rare as compared to the whole HDD failure?

Comment: Its a complex question which can't be simply answered. A big problem with it us " would you recognise a failing hard drive if you saw it". For most people I know the answer is no.  The thing is even if failure is partial it usually gets worse and spreads. Its a bad risk...

Comment: If you want to deap-dive into hardware failures, Backup Blaze are known for keeping track of their disk failures and reporting on them. (There failure rates are much lower then I've seen - presumably because they handle them carefully and have special racks and I overstate the risk), but still with googling if you want to obcess over risk and failure types rather then following best practices.

Comment: My 20% failure rate / year for hdd must be wrong. Please ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Most data center professionals would recommend the [3-2-1 backup strategy](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/the-3-2-1-backup-strategy/). This means keeping (at least) 3 copies of your data:

1. Your original data.
2. An onsite backup on a different medium.
3. An offsite backup.

There are many good reasons for this. For example, the onsite backup can be used to quickly restore all or part of your data when something happens to your original data or the disks it's on, such as complete or partial mechanical or electronical failure, accidental deletion, data corruption etc.

You can (and should) also use your onsite backup to store multiple older versions of your data, so you could, for example, have access to versions of documents as they were a few hours ago, yesterday, a week ago or a month ago. Any backup software worth its salt supports this. Most cloud-based file synchronization platforms (Microsoft OneDrive, Google Drive, etc.) also do this.

However, an onsite copy of your data will not protect your data in case of fire, flooding, theft, deliberate destruction, ransomware etc. That's why you should keep an offsite copy as well.

If you'd like to keep costs down you could make do with just an offsite copy. However, when you need to restore an entire multi-terabyte data set, it could take days or weeks, depending on the speed of your internet connection.

Of course, the costs of your backup strategy should be in balance with the value of your data.

The fact is, disks (and the software controlling them!) can and will fail in many ways, sooner or later, taking your data with them. Keeping all of your valuable data, including its backups, on one disk exposes it to these risks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Seeing by the other two questions this is not really a popular take, but having multiple copies on the same drive is certainly better than having no extra backup at all, even if slightly so. The reason is that unrecoverable bad sectors on a platter may render part of your files unreadable.

Even if you have a lot of bad sectors on your drive, as long as it covers only a small amount of sectors compared to the total number of sectors on the drive, chances are much higher that you will be able to recover all files bit-for-bit intact.

In addition, having multiple copies may make it easier using data recovery to get the data back, for the same reasons (and besides bad sectors, scratches due a head crash for example also may leave at least one of the file copies intact).

In fact, if you have some super important small file (like an encryption key or a password database) and you copy it millions of times on the same disc until full, chances are incredibly high to get the data back, even if you completely shatter the drive and its platters.

One more reason to backup multiple times on one drive is to prevent deleting a (file from a) backup due to human error. For example at the time of a backup restore.

Of course, this is not really what you should be doing, or necessarily good advice. Just backup on different drives and store at difference locations, and perform standard best practices for backup care. But if there's no other drive, and it does not incur too much wear on the drive, indeed every additional backup replication on a drive helps, if only by a little.